# How do I resolve this Python Flask TypeError? Where did I go wrong?

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm very new to this and I ran into a TypeError. I'm trying to simulate a basic web page with flask. I've managed to send the HTML request from a HTML text box to my program. I'm trying to display the response in a table on another page.

This here is my input page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <form action = "/Attendance" method = "POST">
         <p>Enter Employee Code:</p>
         <p><input type = "text" name = "employee_code" /></p>
         <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

The input goes into this program:

```
import pyodbc
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def attendance_fetch():
    return render_template('Attendance_fetch.html')


@app.route('/Attendance', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def database_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        req = request.form['employee_code']

        conn = pyodbc.connect(
                r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, 
*.accdb)};DBQ=E:\xampp\htdocs\S10\SmartOffice.mdb;')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('select * from Employees where EmployeeCode =?', req)

        for i in cursor.fetchall():
            employee_id = str(i[0])
        cursor.execute('select * from AttendanceLogs where EmployeeId=?', employee_id)

        columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
        results = [columns] + [row for row in cursor.fetchall()]
        for result in results:
            return result
            return render_template('Database_file.html', data=result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True)
```

My desire is for the output to go into here display as a table:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
     <title>Attendance Table</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <table border = 1>
     {% for key, value in data() %}
       <tr>
        <th> {{ key }} </th>
        <td> {{ value }} </td>
       </tr>
     {% endfor %}
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

But I'm getting the error:

" {rv.**class**.**name**}.".format(rv=rv)

TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding to your question. You are getting some ID in first `Attendance_fetch.html` page and then getting details from database and want to display that information in table format in `Database_file.html` page.

Your `/Attendance` Logic might be like below where you are sending table headers and values in two different lists.

```
@app.route('/Attendance', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def database_file():
if request.method == 'POST':
    # DB Logic 
    headers = ["Name", "Emp code"]
    values = ["Vikas Saini", "100"]
    return render_template('Database_file.html', headers=headers, values=values)
```

Then In `Database_file.html`, you can display your table using below like code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
     <title>Attendance Table</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <table border = 1>
     <tr>
     {% for header in headers %}
        <th> {{ header }} </th>
     {% endfor %}
     </tr>

     <tr>
     {% for value in values %}
        <td> {{ value }} </td>
     {% endfor %}
     </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You return wrong response, should be object Response.
just remove line:

First

```
columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
results = [columns] + [row for row in cursor.fetchall()]
for result in results:
    return result   <-- !!!!!REMOVE THIS LINE!!!!!
    return render_template('Database_file.html', data=result)
```

Second
It's because you trying to call list object with `data()` Just remove brackets from data. Instead `data()` write **data**

```
{% for key, value in data %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried that but now it says {% for key, value in data() %} 
                                                                                                                           TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: It's because you trying to call list object with `data()`

Just remove brackets from `data`. Instead `data()` write `data`

```
{% for key, value in data %} 
```